# Transfer Function of a pressure sensor - what does it tell me?

Tags: sensor, transfer-function, pressure

so I'm trying to get a pressure sensor for a water pump and in the Datasheets they state different transfer functions within the series. I know that the transfer function describes the input and output of a system. But when the datasheet gives this: [image: Datasheet]

What does that mean? What is it describing?

I'm sorry if this is a very simple question.

Comment: What does footnote 3 say? Isn't this explained somewhere else in the data sheet?

Comment: The footnote only sais that the Transfer Function varies by pressure range selection and says to look in some tables. But the tables only say for which pressure to use which transfer function. They do use it in a calculation but only to calculate Pressure. But that doesn't explain what they say in the part of the Datasheet that I have in my post

Comment: Can you give a link to the datasheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incremental value for a signal may be calibrated more accurately between 2 active thresholds of range rather than 0 to 100% which be more non-linear at the extent of the range.

For best accuracy, choose the range that is closest to your application. That seems to be 0 to 100% for a pump.  But what is the ratio at max pressure to the sensor is a question TBD.

**Depending on your pump pressure to sensor range ratio you may want B or A.**

B has a 10:1 span or gain ratio yet only 22.5% of max range may fit your selection.

Since pumps are calibrated at a fixed temperature and all pressure sensors have a **Gain** and **Offset** error, no matter how small, these are 3 optional ways to improve your accuracy by the OEM's calibration method.

Knowing the model gain and offset version A,B,C you can then compute the sensitivity of the sensor:

Gain =  Count/Range , where Range = Pmax-Min   A=80%, B= 20%, C=  60% of total rating. So **gain or count sensitivity depends on the max P (psi) and the transfer function A,B,C calibration.**
Offset=  Count = 0 for Pressure = 0 bar, as it is a **differential pressure type.**

The total error depends on customer "auto-zero" or offset calibration with 0 pressure.
[image]

[Datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2548296.pdf) *which was missing in question*

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer!

Comment: I didn't quite understand the first part of your answer. What influence does the span/gain ratio and max range have?

Comment: For the same count if the % pressure span changes, so does the gain and count for the total range

Comment: So in short (to make sure I understood it correctly): The percentages given in the datasheet for the transfer function tell me the range (80, 20, 60%) and with that I can determine the Gain or count sensitivity by dividing the count (2^24) by the range (in %) ?

Comment: yes that is how gain is defined.  unlike saturation where the gain goes to zero